# Form not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am having trouble sending the information from my PHP form to the email address. I am fairly new to PHP. Code is below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$myEmail = "shivambh28@gmail.com";

if (empty($name) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
  $error = 'Please make sure to double check the fields for errors.';
} elseif (!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $error = 'Email is incorrect';
} else {
  $headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $myEmail\r\n";
  $headers .= "Return-Path: $myEmail\r\n";
  $headers .= "CC: $email\r\n";
  $headers .= "BCC: $myEmail\r\n";

  if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
    $to = $myEmail;
    $subject = $subject;
    $message = $message;
    $from = $email;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    echo "Mail Sent.";
  } else {
    echo 'failure to send email';
  }
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/email/"  method="POST">
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
    <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
    <textarea placeholder="Your Message" id="message" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

NOTE: I am using WP CMS.

Comment: looks to me as if you are sending the email twice

Comment: Default method for forms is `GET`. You need to add `method='POST'` to your `<form>` tag in order to use `$_POST` in the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is missing the `method` attribute. edit the code so that your form has `method` POST.

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" action="contact.tpl.php" method="POST">
```

secondly remove one of your `mail` function calls. if not your email will be sent twice

Comment: Not a problem. Looking at the code, looks like the second mail call is sending the same email to himself (manual carbon copy?)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code.It was sending mail by 2times

```
$to = $myEmail;
$subject = $subject;
$message = $message;
$from = $email;
$headers = "From:" . $from;

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {

    echo "Mail Sent.";
} else {
    echo 'failure to send email';
}
```

And your **form method** is like `POST`

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

And main thing your file name is either `contact.php` or `contact.tpl` **NOT** `contact.tpl.php`

Comment: I think he is meaning to send the email twice. Once to the recipient in `$to` and once to himself (ie `$myEmail`)

Comment: Are you getting `POST` variables..??

Comment: @MichaelWheeler where is `$to` then in his code for first mail function..??

Comment: @Gautam3164, not sure what you mean.. I am pretty new to PHP.

Comment: See my last line of the ans @Shivam

Comment: @Gautam3164 I would imagine there is a copy-paste error in there, and `$to` should actually be `$email`

Comment: @MichaelWheeler actually its not a problem I thnk so

Comment: @Shivam and also check your `spam` also

Comment: Checked spam, still nothing. I think the reason behind it all is the action call. I am using WordPress CMS, so WP does not read relative file paths. I am trying to figure this out...

Comment: Ohh...Then at first you need to tell that @Shivam ;-)

Comment: Sorry, realized it a bit late. I connected the paths but page not found shows up only.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `.` (*period*) missing from the first `$headers` variable declaration. Might help.

Answer (score 0):

Form method **POST** is missing in the form tag.

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" action="contact.tpl.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong parameter `$to` in `mail()`

Try

```
....
....
//// use $email here not $to which is not initialised yet
if ( mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
```

**is place of**

```
 if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
```

Comment: Check in `spam or junk folder`. And use `die()` for every check if a user not fills `name or subject, etc`, also after `mails sent or not`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = $myEmail;
$subject = $subject;
$message = $message;
$from = $email;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
   echo "Mail Sent";
} else {
   echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: How is this code different from the OP? I just suppresses the errors `mail()` may raise.